# cannot find serevr.js in "Pro Javascript for Web Dev" book

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone help me find and run the server.js file in the "download" files of the book "Pro Javascript for Web Dev" by Adam Freeman? In Page 8 it explains it as:

> I rely on some third-party modules, so run the following command after
>   you have installed the
>
> Node.js package:
>
> ```
> npm install node-static jqtpl
> ```
>
> This command downloads and installs the node-static and jqtpl packages
>   that I use to deliver static and templated content in the examples.
>   The command will generate output similar to this (but you may see some
>   additional warnings, which can be ignored):
>
> ```
> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-static
> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jqtpl
> npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jqtpl
> npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-static
> node-static@0.5.9 ./node_modules/node-static
> jqtpl@1.0.9 ./node_modules/jqtpl
> ```

However I don't get these messages and my examples do not run with right content. Instead I get these:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-70-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "node-static" "jqptl"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/jqptl
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'jqptl' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/nesa/www/pro-javascript/npm-debug.log
```

Can anyone help me? The link to the download of the files is:

http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1297/

Comment: What messages *do* you get instead? Is the `node_modules` directory created?

Comment: it is like this:   `npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-70-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "node-static" "jqptl"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/jqptl
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'jqptl' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.`

Comment: Update your question with this information, not the comment section.

Comment: @deceze  I just updated the question now.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It installs without a hitch for me.

Comment: *Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/jqptl* — That URL does 404 when I visit it though. My wild speculation guesses it might be due to you using an old version of node and npm. (I'm on 6.6.09 and 3.10.5)

Comment: My node version is: v4.4.3

Comment: @Vennesa — Yes, your error message said that. That's why I commented that it was an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Type **jqtpl** correctly, you are typing **jqptl** instead. Check you error log to see that

Comment: do sudo npm install -g npm then try again

Comment: Why would using `sudo` help? There is no mention of a permissions problem writing any files. The command used doesn't use the `-g` flag so it isn't trying to install globally.

Comment: "do sudo npm install -g npm then try again" — **Don't**, globally installed modules for local projects are a terrible idea.

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks I will remember this point from now on. I was just trying everything I could to get the examples running but my server.js is just not there...So I cant...